# How to include context elements in search space when using jQuery( selector [, context ] )

Tags: jquery

I have an existing collection of elements that I want to change if they match a given selector.  I want to do the same to these items' descendants (recursively).  This seems like the function of `jQuery( selector [, context ] )`.  However, the resulting set does not include the parent elements.  I want to query them too.  Can this be done with one command?

for example,

```
var els = $('<div foo="bar">')
$("[foo]", els ); // finds nothing
els.filter("[foo]"); // finds div
```

But filter does not search descendants, so

```
var els = $('<div foo="bar"><span foo="foobar"></div>')
$("[foo]", els ); // finds span
els.filter("[foo]"); // finds div
```

What's the best way to find both the span and the div?  Use both commands?  Is there a single line command to find both?  Better than this anyway?

```
var els = $('<div foo="bar"><span foo="foobar"></div>')
var selection = $("[foo]", els ); // finds inner elements
selection = selection.add(els.filter("[foo]")); // then adds on parents that match the selector
```

Comment: `$("[foo]", els ).add(els)`, is the way to go, elements passed as context are not part of the selection.

Comment: I don't want to add all els, just elements within els that match "[foo]" selector.

Comment: @adeneo and you need to make sure els matches the selector.  Then it becomes the posted example.

Comment: `$('*', 'div').addBack().filter('[foo]')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The context is for supplying an element or collection of elements to look **within**, meaning the *descendants* of those elements. It does not filter like `.filter` does, it's more like `.find`.

If you want both, you'll have to use both:

```
$("[foo]", els ).add( els.filter("[foo]") );
```

or use a parent element.

```
$("[foo]", $("<div>").html(els) );
```

so, no there isn't a better way.

The second method is how jQuery's .load method does it, but i wouldn't consider it any better.

https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.9-stable/src/ajax.js#L176

Comment: @AlexMA sorry, hit submit too early.

Comment: I suspected so.  Seems like it would be a bit nicer to have the option of including the context element so the search is more efficient and code less funky looking, but this isn't so bad.

Comment: And happily, it looks like there are no duplicates in case the context is something like $("*") (which would be silly, but still).

Comment: Yes, jQuery automatically runs the `$.unique` method before returning results for traversal methods, resulting in a sorted unique array of DOM elements.

Comment: "it's more like `.find`" - it actually *is* find. `// HANDLE: $(expr, $(...))
   } else if ( !context || context.jquery ) {
    return ( context || rootjQuery ).find( selector );`